# iOS 9: Renewal and distribution of provisioning profile of Enterprise app without IPA build

Tags: profile, enterprise, provisioning, ios9.2, renewal

In iOS 7, for renewal of provisioning profile (for enterprise app), we used to follow the below process:

1. Generate a new provisioning profile from the Apple member center.
2. Install the new provisioning profile to all the devices.

In iOS 9, it seems that the steps are not working. I am unable to install the provisioning profile directly to devices. Rebuilding IPA and distributing to all the devices is not an option at this point of time.

What are the other options that I have? Anyone faced the same issue? What's the workaround for this issue?